# python and dynamic-ish lambda combined with any/all matching?

Tags: python

I am trying to do something like this:

```
filters = {'ok1': lambda x: x['a'] == 1, 'ok2': lambda x: x['b'] == 2}
d = [{'a': 1, 'b': 3}, {'a': 5, 'b': 2},{'a': 6, 'b': 7}]
c = filter(lambda z: filters['ok1'] and filters['ok2'], d)
e =  filter(lambda z: filters['ok1'] or filters['ok2'], d)
print(d)
print(c)
print(e)
```

Where I configurable list of lambda functions, and then filtering a list of items by that. Here I would like to expect `c` to have zero items and `e` to have two due to the logic (or I might even employ `any()` and `all()` calls).

Comment: I think you forgot some `(z)` calls inside the `filter` `lambda`s. Now the `lambda z:...` part returns functions.

Answer (score 2):

`lambda z: filters['ok1'] and filters['ok2']` means nothing, it should be `lambda z: filters['ok1'](z) and filters['ok2'](z)`.

You didn't even call the function I believe.

Comment: That doesn't "mean nothing", it just doesn't mean what OP wants it to mean.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Whatever, it just means nothing in OP's context.

Comment: It literally "means" `lambda z: filters['ok2']`.

Comment: Is there some way to make this work? `f = filter(lambda x: any(filters[z] for z in filters))`

Comment: Sure, any(filters[z](x) for z in filters)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Sraw's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52938098/160511) I was able to clarify what I was after, and my any/all works as follows:

```
filters = {'ok1': lambda x: x['a'] == 1, 'ok2': lambda z: z['b'] == 2}
d = [{'a': 1, 'b': 3}, {'a': 5, 'b': 2},{'a': 6, 'b': 7}]
alls = filter(lambda x: all(filters[z](x) for z in filters), d)
anys = filter(lambda x: any(filters[z](x) for z in filters), d)
print(alls)
print(anys)
```

Comment: I think it can be even simplified, `filter(lambda x: all(filter(x) for filter in filters.values()), d)`